# Overriding or inheriting Static Class

Tags: c#

I am trying to add additional methods to a static class.

For example, I have a class `Foo` with some methods.

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static void Member1()
    { /* ... */ }

    public static void Member2()
    { /* ... */ }

    public static void Member3()
    { /* ... */  }
}
```

I would like to add another method, `Member4()` from another `class`, but I cannot access `Foo`.

Is it possible to create a new static class that inherits the methods from `Foo`? If not, how would I otherwise move these methods to a new class so I can add my methods?

Comment: Why do you want to add the members to that static class? Why not create a new one? Not to mention that global mutable objects aren't such a great idea.

Comment: please enlighten me. I'm new to objects and static classes.

Comment: Enlighten you as to what?

Comment: There are two type of abstractions in C#; abstract class vs interface class. when you declare static, it means you can't instantiate that class & static methods cannot be inherited or overridden, and that is why they can't be abstract.so you are declaring static on the type.

Comment: Under the hood, a `static` class is marked both `abstract`, so you can't instantiate it, and `sealed`, so you can't inherit from it.

Comment: maybe you can use sigleton pattern , it almost like static class , and you can Inherit it also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static members belong to the class, not the instance, and therefore are not subject to polymorphism. You cannot inherit a static class because there are no methods to inherit. And there is really no reason to inherit a static class, as you can just make a new static class and add your new methods there. If you want to have all the methods in one place, you can make wrapper methods like the ones shown below.

```
static class Foo {
    public void Member1() { /* ... */ }
    public void Member2() { /* ... */ }
    public void Member3() { /* ... */ }
}

static class FooPlus {
    public void Member1()
    {
        Foo.Member1();
    }
    // Repeat for all other methods
    // ...

    public void Member4() { /* ... */ }
}
```